# Creating Albums on iCloud and storing different photos in each album using cloudKit Swift 4

Tags: swift4, icloud, cloudkit, photos

I am new to iOS Development and I am creating this project where I need to use `CloudKit` in order to `save photos` on `iCloud`. So basically my app will allow user to create different photo albums and inside every album adding photos of his/her choice, the catch is user will only be able to see this adding album page when a secret password is entered on a separate page.

Basically I need some guidance from you guys in order to achieve this task. After searching online I came to know that i have to use `CloudKit` in order to integrate `iCloud` in my app.

Basically i am looking for answers to this following questions :

- After integrating `CloudKit` what am I suppose to do?
- How can i create different folders on iCloud and how can I possibly give unique ids to them?
- How can I upload photos to specific album?

If someone has reference code to such app,it will be of great help.
looking forward to get my doubts cleared.

Comment: I think you should search for any third party support framework for cloud kit. Because you need to encode, decode image with file manager and create and maintain the connection to file and read-write permissions.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for replying. I understand the encoding and decoding part but my main concern over here is creating albums on a button click and then on click of that albums creating a collection view that can store photos to that particular album. Any idea how can i achieve this on icloud using cloudKit